# Как правильно остановить скрипт по условию? PHP

Tags: php

задумался над тем как правильно остановить скрипт, если не выполняется условие

Пример:

```
<?php

if(1!==1){
    exit();
}

//Основной код

?>
```

Или

```
<?php

if(1!==1){
    exit();
}else{
    //Основной код
}

?>
```

Есть ли различие между ними? Может ли скрипт каким-то чудом пропустить условие?

Comment: Чудом пропустить? Может. Но с тем же чудом он может пропустить и `else`. Так что не парьтесь и пользуйтесь первым вариантом

Comment: 1 не равно 1 он конечно чудом пропустит

Comment: @Naumov, пример как никак)

Comment: Ну если переживаете, что пропустит лупите сразу без каких либо условий `exit()`))